# Android App and website login authentication issue

Tags: android, authentication, web

I'm developing an app and website for the same system. If a user changes the password from the website and same user opens the app after that, it should ask for login again?
How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If user changes the password from the website it will be stored to your server. In the server code you have to write down a function which will identify this change and will send a push notification to your mobile application.
In the mobile app, when you receive the notification just log out the user from the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different way . Simple Call the login api with user_name and password And check the authentication every time when app is opened .